# Diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Suppose that $A$ is a $n \times n$ complex normal matrix. We know that there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^{-1}AU$ is a diagonal matrix. My question is as follows:
In the process of diagonalization, is there a unitary matrix $U$ such that $UAU$ is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Right away I can think of one example: if $U=I_n$ and $A$ is diagonal. But in general I don't believe so.

Answer (score 2):

The Eigendecomposition of $A$ is $A=U\Lambda U^{-1}$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and $U$ is unitary. Hence, $U^{-1}=U^*$ and $U^{-1}AU=\Lambda$

In order to $UAU=\Lambda$ hold, one needs to have $U^{-1}=U$, that is $U$ should be an involutory matrix: $U^{2}=I$.

The above conditions can happen jointly when $U=I$. That is, when $A$ is diagonal already, But it is not necessary. For instance if $U=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: ‎Let $ A =‎‎ ‎‎ \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}‎$‎ and ‎$ U =‎‎ ‎‎ \begin{bmatrix}
  ‎\dfrac{1}{‎\sqrt{2}‎}‎ & ‎\dfrac{1}{‎\sqrt{2}‎} \\
  ‎\dfrac{1}{‎\sqrt{2}‎} & ‎\dfrac{-1}{‎\sqrt{2}‎} \\
\end{bmatrix}‎$‎. We can see $UAU= \begin{bmatrix}
  1& 0 \\
  0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}‎$. So it is not necessary $U=I$.